# Cast timestamp to timestamp with time zone

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying convert timestamp to timestamp with time zone with adding GMT time zone:

```
to_timestamp(to_char(t.time_started, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
  || nvl2(t.time_started, ' GMT', null), ('DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss tzd'))
```

but this gets ORA-01812 date format not recognized. How can I specify add the time zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [the `to_timestamp_tz()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions214.htm#SQLRF06143), not just `to_timestamp`; the 'tzd` format element isn't recognised for that, hence your error:

```
select to_timestamp_tz(to_char(t.time_started, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
  || nvl2(t.time_started, ' GMT', null), ('DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss tzd'))
from t;

TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(TO_CHAR(T.TIME_STARTED,'DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI:SS')||NVL2(T.TIME_STARTED,'GMT',NULL),('DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI:SSTZD'))
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
05-JAN-15 18.09.28.000000000 EUROPE/LONDON
```

As you'll notice, you're losing the fractional seconds with the format models you've chosen.

You can also specify the time zone a value represents with [the `at time zone` expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e17118/expressions007.htm):

```
select t.time_started at time zone 'GMT' from t;

T.TIME_STARTEDATTIMEZONE'GMT'     
-----------------------------------
05-JAN-15 18.12.53.419495000 GMT
```

Or you can use `cast`, as your question title suggested, which I believe assumes the system time zone:

```
select cast(t.time_started as timestamp with time zone) from t;

CAST(T.TIME_STARTEDASTIMESTAMPWITHTIMEZONE)
-------------------------------------------
05-JAN-15 18.14.19.236338000 EUROPE/LONDON
```

I'm in the UK so that works for me, but if your server is in a different time zone you might then need to convert it.

Comment: Unless there are very specific needs, using the `AT TIME ZONE` clause is definitively the way to go here

Comment: Agreed; just covering the bases, from the OP's original query and the title. Seems I should have emphasised the `at time zone` option more though.

Answer (score 2):

If the column `t.time_started` is of type `TIMESTAMP`, and the request is to interpret this timestamp in a given time zone, then the function `FROM_TZ` is to be used here.

In contrast, the `AT TIME ZONE` Clause is used to move a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value from one time zone to another time zone.

This means that with the following `SELECT` statement first an implicit conversion (using the current session time zone) of the `TIMESTAMP` value into a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value takes place and then this value is displayed in another time zone, which may not be the expected result and the solution to the question.

```
select t.time_started at time zone 'GMT' from t
```

See the following example which shows the difference. (My session time zone is currently +2:00).

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
   time_started    TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO t
     VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

SELECT * FROM t;


SELECT FROM_TZ(t.time_started, 'GMT') as T1, t.time_started AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' as T2 FROM t
```

The result is:

```
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|                T1                 |                T2                 |
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| 2019-07-16 12:17:29,068660 +00:00 | 2019-07-16 10:17:29,068660 +00:00 |
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Both values are displayed in GMT, but are clearly different.